# How do you handle mouseover events with overlapping TextFields?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, mouseover

I have a horizontal stack of buttons that represent tabs, and each button has a `TextField` inside of it that is larger than the dimensions of the button so that they overlap. Like this (the dotted line is a `TextField` and the red box is the area where mousing over does not work due to the overlap):

[image]

Each of these buttons is an instance of a `TabButton`, which has a class definition like this:

```
package src
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class TabButton extends MovieClip
    {
        // Stage Instances
        public var mcHitZone:MovieClip;
        public var mcText:TextField;

        public function TabButton()
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            // Disable mouse input on everything except for the hit zone since that's where mouse handling should be done.
            mcText.mouseEnabled = false;

            mcHitZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouse, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function onMouse(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("Mouse event: " + name + " " + e.type);
        }
    }
}
```

Each TabButton has a `mcHitZone` that I'm attaching the mouse handler to, which is the black area on the above image. Since the `TextField` is much larger than the button itself, it needs to be completely ignored for mouse input handling so I'm turning it off with `mcText.mouseEnabled = false;`, which seems to work when mousing within a single button, but when mousing over the overlap area (the red box) the `TextField` will block mouse input from the other button.

Is there any way to make this work so that the `TextField` does not block mouse input on anything that it overlaps with?

I've uploaded the FLA and AS that I've been testing this with [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9dakdmr5ce40101/MouseTest.zip). If you run it, it will trace when you roll over a particular button. If you try to mouse over the red area of the leftmost button then it won't work.

Comment: The question is : why your text field is overlapping ? If you don't need that white space, just remove it and the problem will disappear !

Comment: I don't have a choice, unfortunately. I can't go into the details, but the text field just has to be like that. This is a greatly simplified example of the actual libraries I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button have three movieClips, mcHitZone, mcText, and TabButton itself.
So when you place two buttons close, the up tabButton(not it's Child mcText) will affect the under tabButton.

I advise your tabButton not extends movieClip, just use the mcHitZone as Button's skin, then add it to your stage.

Just as the comment say, you can also make the tabButton's mouseEnabled false. I mixed up mouseEnabled and mouseChildren.

Comment: oh! That's right, the TabButton sizes to the size of the largest child clip, which would be the mcText, right? If TabButton doesn't extend from MovieClip, then where would I add the mcHitZone and mcText? They have to be children of something.

Comment: Yes. you can add them to something you added your tabButton.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I'll experiment a bit. Thanks.

Comment: The proper solution should be `this.mouseEnabled=false;` in the `TabButton` constructor, this way the only part of the TabButton to react on mouse would be `mcHitZone`.

Comment: @Vesper you're right! For some reason I thought that setting it on the `TabButton` would completely disable it for all children, but I guess that's why there is a separate `mouseChildren` flag. Thanks for that.